# Silverstripe ORM: strange behaviour with boolean ->filter()

Tags: mysql, orm, silverstripe

I've got a strange problem with the Silverstripe ORM. A function in a controller retrieves items from the db, while selecting if a boolean flag is set:

```
function getMosaic($page_type) {
    //$page_type = "isPageFilter"; //when uncommented,it works!
    return Mosaic::get()->filter($page_type,1)->toArray();
}

$this->getMosaic("isPageFilter");
```

Strangely, this yields an error:

> Couldn't run query: SELECT DISTINCT "Mosaic"."ClassName",
>   "Mosaic"."Created", "Mosaic"."LastEdited", "Mosaic"."Type",
>   "Mosaic"."Size", "Mosaic"."HomePage", "Mosaic"."FilterPage",
>   "Mosaic"."DetailPage", "Mosaic"."Position", "Mosaic"."PackageID",
>   "Mosaic"."ID", CASE WHEN "Mosaic"."ClassName" IS NOT NULL THEN
>   "Mosaic"."ClassName" ELSE 'Mosaic' END AS "RecordClassName" FROM
>   "Mosaic" WHERE ("1" = '1') Unknown column '1' in 'where clause'

To make matters more strange, when I uncomment the "$page_type = "isPageFilter", it works!

When I do this:

```
    $page_type2 = $page_type."2";
    return Mosaic::get()->filter($page_type,1)->filter($page_type2,1)->toArray();
```

Now I get an error too (column inPageFilter2 does not exist) , but the "1"="1" has been replaced bij "isPageFilter"=1.

I'm a little flabbergasted and I am wondering if I need a good exorcist, I am going slightly mad myself, or if I'm just plain old overlooking something obvious here...

**Update:** I changed the code to

```
Mosaic::get()->where("'".$page_type."' = 1")->toArray();
```

And now it works. I think I am on to a Silverstripe bug...

Comment: filter() expects a valid column. "1" isn't a valid column so it won't work. As your update shows, you can use where() for raw queries.

Comment: As you can see in the example, I don't supply "1" as a column. I supply "isFilterPage", but it somehow gets exchanged by "1".

Comment: My guess would be that you're calling the function from elsewhere. Calling $Mosaic in a template for example would call getMosaic. I'd review the backtrace to see where the function call is coming from. Calling $this->Mosaic would also trigger it.

Comment: I used a simplified example. In reality this is the function:
public function getMosaic($page_type="HomePage"). Also, if you look at the second code block ($page_type2 = $page_type."2"), you'll see that this is not the case.